# Using PySpark window functions with conditions to add rows

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a need to be able to add new rows to a PySpark df will values based upon the contents of other rows with a common id. There will eventually millions of ids with lots rows for each id. I have tried the below method which works but seems overly complicated.

I start with a df in the format below (but in reality have more columns):

```
+-------+----------+-------+
|   id  | variable | value |
+-------+----------+-------+
|     1 | varA     |    30 |
|     1 | varB     |     1 |
|     1 | varC     |    -9 |
+-------+----------+-------+
```

Currently I am pivoting this df to get it in the following format:

```
+-----+------+------+------+
|  id | varA | varB | varC |
+-----+------+------+------+
|   1 |   30 |    1 |   -9 |
+-----+------+------+------+
```

On this df I can then use the standard withColumn and when functionality to add new columns based on the values in other columns. For example:

```
df = df.withColumn("varD", when((col("varA") > 16) & (col("varC") != -9)), 2).otherwise(1)
```

Which leads to:

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+
|  id | varA | varB | varC | varD |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
|   1 |   30 |    1 |   -9 |    1 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

I can then pivot this df back to the original format leading to this:

```
+-------+----------+-------+
|   id  | variable | value |
+-------+----------+-------+
|     1 | varA     |    30 |
|     1 | varB     |     1 |
|     1 | varC     |    -9 |
|     1 | varD     |     1 |
+-------+----------+-------+
```

This works but seems like it could, with millions of rows, lead to expensive and unnecessary operations. It feels like it should be doable without the need to pivot and unpivot the data. Do I need to do this?

I have read about Window functions and it sounds as if they may be another way to achieve the same result but to be honest I am struggling to get started with them. I can see how they can be used to generate a value, say a sum, for each id, or to find a maximum value but have not found a way to even get started on applying complex conditions that lead to a new row.

Any help to get started with this problem would be gratefully received.

Comment: Do you mean from rows to columns? Something like spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table_name").groupBy("id").pivot("variable").agg(first("value")).

Comment: best way to get answer though is to start your own question with an example of what you want to achieve and a summary of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas_udf` for adding/deleting rows/col on grouped data, and  implement your processing logic in pandas udf.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

row_schema = StructType(
    [StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
     StructField("variable", StringType(), True),
     StructField("value", IntegerType(), True)]
)

@F.pandas_udf(row_schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def addRow(pdf):
    val = 1
    if  (len(pdf.loc[(pdf['variable'] == 'varA') & (pdf['value'] > 16)]) > 0 ) & \
        (len(pdf.loc[(pdf['variable'] == 'varC') & (pdf['value'] != -9)]) > 0):
        val = 2
    return pdf.append(pd.Series([1, 'varD', val], index=['id', 'variable', 'value']), ignore_index=True)

df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 'varA', 30],
                            [1, 'varB', 1],
                            [1, 'varC', -9]
                            ], schema=['id', 'variable', 'value'])

df.groupBy("id").apply(addRow).show()
```

which resuts

```
+---+--------+-----+
| id|variable|value|
+---+--------+-----+
|  1|    varA|   30|
|  1|    varB|    1|
|  1|    varC|   -9|
|  1|    varD|    1|
+---+--------+-----+
```

Comment: This more-or-less worked for me so marked as the correct answer. Thanks. The only extras I needed to do was convert anything not a string to a string (as a package it uses only works with strings and bytes not integers) and set the id value to be the current id and not '1' every time.

Comment: A `pandas_udf`/UDAF is a really expensive way to do this (spark -> pandas/pyarrow data -> python UDF -> pandas/pyarrow data -> spark). A much faster way would be to add a an array column to your dataframe, add values to the array column and then explode it.